# Multiple checkbox filters return server error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, mixitup

I am trying to set up a Wordpress portfolio page with multiple checkbox filtering options. The js-code and some HTML is from MixItUp (http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/iwcap).

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Filter categories -->
    <div class="col-md-4">      
        <form class="controls" id="Filters">
            <?php
            $count1 = 0;
            // all products of category with sortable
            function enc8($c){  return utf8_encode($c); }
            $terms1 = get_terms( product_group );
            $count1 = count($terms1);
            echo '<fieldset>';
                if ( $count1 > 0 ){
                        foreach ( $terms1 as $term1 ) {
                            $termname1 = strtolower($term1->name);
                            $termname1 = str_replace(array(enc8('ä'),enc8('Ä'),enc8('ö'),enc8('Ö'),enc8('ü'),enc8('Ü'),enc8('ß'),' &amp; ',' '),array('ae','Ae','oe','Oe','ue','Ue','ss','-','-'),$termname1);
                            echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=".'.$termname1.'"/><label> '.$term1->name.'</label></div>';
                        }
                }
            echo '</fieldset>';
            ?>
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="Reset">Reset</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">      
        <form class="controls" id="Filters">
            <?php
            $count2 = 0;    
            // all products of category with sortable
            function enc8($c){  return utf8_encode($c); }
            $terms2 = get_terms( product_category );
            $count2 = count($terms2);
            echo '<fieldset>';
                if ( $count2 > 0 ){
                        foreach ( $terms2 as $term2 ) {
                            $termname2 = strtolower($term2->name);
                            $termname2 = str_replace(array(enc8('ä'),enc8('Ä'),enc8('ö'),enc8('Ö'),enc8('ü'),enc8('Ü'),enc8('ß'),' &amp; ',' '),array('ae','Ae','oe','Oe','ue','Ue','ss','-','-'),$termname2);
                            echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=".'.$termname2.'"/><label> '.$term2->name.'</label></div>';
                        }
                }
            echo '</fieldset>';
            ?>
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="Reset">Reset</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The first taxonomy filter (product_group) works just fine. However, when I add the second one (product_category) the page partly crashes and Chrome returns the following error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

The HTML output looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">      
    <form class="controls" id="Filters">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value=".class01"><label> Class01</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value=".class02"><label> Class02</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value=".class03"><label> Class03</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="Reset">Reset</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">      
    <form class="controls" id="Filters">
    <!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: http://www.w3-edge.com/wordpress-plugins/

    Page Caching using disk: enhanced (User is logged in)

    Served from: mydomain.org @ 2016-02-21 17:03:37 by W3 Total Cache -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: How many check boxes are there? It's unlikely but is there a chance you're hitting over 1k items submitted? What values are being submitted to the server?

Comment: There are currently six checkboxes for the first filter (I reduced the output for the sample to three). It is very unlikely that there will be more than about 20 for each in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. The problem was that the following function

```
function enc8($c){ return utf8_encode($c); }
```

was twice in the code. Combining the two filters to a single function and a bit of renaming some variables was the solution:

```
<form class="controls" id="Filters">
    <?php
    $countgroups = 0;
    $countcats = 0;

    function enc8($c){ return utf8_encode($c); }

    $groups = get_terms( product_group );
    $countgroups = count($groups);                          
    $cats = get_terms( product_category );
    $countcats = count($cats);

    echo '<fieldset class="groups"><h4>Produktgruppen</h4>';
        if ( $countgroups > 0 ){
                foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
                    $groupname = strtolower($group->name);
                    $groupname = str_replace(array(enc8('ä'),enc8('Ä'),enc8('ö'),enc8('Ö'),enc8('ü'),enc8('Ü'),enc8('ß'),' &amp; ',' '),array('ae','Ae','oe','Oe','ue','Ue','ss','-','-'),$groupname);
                    echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=".'.$groupname.'"/><label>'.$group->name.'</label></div>';
                }
        }
    echo '</fieldset>';
    echo '<fieldset class="cats"><h4>Produktkategorien</h4>';
        if ( $countcats > 0 ){
                foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                    $catname = strtolower($cat->name);
                    $catname = str_replace(array(enc8('ä'),enc8('Ä'),enc8('ö'),enc8('Ö'),enc8('ü'),enc8('Ü'),enc8('ß'),' &amp; ',' '),array('ae','Ae','oe','Oe','ue','Ue','ss','-','-'),$catname);
                    echo '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=".'.$catname.'"/><label>'.$cat->name.'</label></div>';
                }
        }
    echo '</fieldset>';
    ?>
    <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="Reset">Reset</a>
</form>
```

Works like a charm now :)